# IOS - after jquery animate scrollTop, it prevents divs being clicakble until user scrolls manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

```
$('.topNavigationBtn').on('click',function (e) {  
    var target = $(this).attr('targetId');      
    $("body").animate({ scrollTop: $(target).offset().top }, 1000);
})
```

Please note this isn't on all IOS devices, but on some, after the first animation, until the user manually scrolls the page the topNavigationBtn's are no longer clickable. Any ideas why this would be would much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to hack.
If you add a div at the bottom of the page, that you change the height of on animate complete, this then lets IOS update the scrollTop, without the user needing to scroll themselves.
J